# dense_RANK() function, how can I fix? oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, dense-rank

My code is like this right now

```
select c.id_number
      ,dense_RANK() OVER (Partition by c.id_number ORDER BY c.id_number) "rank"
from  children c
```

now it is showing like this

```
id_Number ___ rank
001           1
002           1
003           1
003           1
004           1
004           1
004           1
```

BUT I would like to show like this,

```
id_Number ___ rank
001           1
002           1
003           1
003           2
004           1
004           2
004           3
```

I try like this

```
 select c.id_number
          ,RANK() OVER (Partition by c.id_number ORDER BY c.id_number) "rank"
 from  children c
```

but it did not work what I want,

what is the best way to code like what I want

Comment: @JNevill Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: No prob. Gordon stuck this in an answer, so I'm going to kill the comment answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `row_number()`:

```
select c.id_number,
       row_number() over (Partition by c.id_number ORDER BY c.id_number) as "rank"
from  children c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Dense_Rank will assign a rank number. In case of equality, it will assign the same number for all the equal rows and then move to the next number (that's where "dense" comes from). In your example 003 is the first one from its partition, so it will have the rank of 1. The next 003 will not be the first from its partition, but being equal to the previous one, it will have the same rank of 1. So that's why your solution doesn't work.

If you want it to work, just use **row_number** instead. This one will only care about the order and not how the row relates to other rows.

```
    select c.id_number
        ,row_number() OVER (Partition by c.id_number ORDER BY c.id_number) "rank"
    from  children c
```